# How to create an expanded function to be optimized based on the number of peaks from a distribution?

Tags: python, optimization, gaussian

I want to decompose a distribution in a set of individual gaussian distributions.
For example:

```
 f = np.array([ 3.00007453,  3.00080131,  3.00670925,  3.04374984,  3.22218031,
        3.87874542,  5.70679883,  9.49405098, 15.13899976, 20.70462534,
       23.27772517, 21.74836598, 18.51405863, 17.61004214, 20.87567502,
       25.97834859, 28.41103287, 25.85310026, 20.47067556, 16.63620493,
       16.69447783, 19.10087608, 20.27772522, 18.05713464, 13.31940778,
        8.52009358,  5.30079298,  3.74693462,  3.18885332,  3.03718737,
        3.00570287,  3.00068111,  3.00006335,  3.00000459,  3.00000026,
        3.00000001,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,
        3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,
        3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ])

plt.plot(f)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKVbU.png)

The distribution can contain many peaks. I have wrote a code that evaluate the number of peaks and optimize to the number of gaussians needed to explain the number of peaks found returning the parameters for all gaussian curves.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    from scipy.signal import find_peaks


def Gauss_1(xdata, H,  A, mean, std):
    return H + A*np.exp(-(xdata-mean)**2/(2*std**2))

def Gauss_2(xdata, H1, A1, mean1, std1, A2, mean2, std2, ):
    return H1 + A1*np.exp(-(xdata-mean1)**2/(2*std1**2)) + A2*np.exp(-(xdata-mean2)**2/(2*std2**2))

def Gauss_3(xdata, H1, A1, mean1, std1, A2, mean2, std2,  A3, mean3, std3 ):
    return H1 + A1*np.exp(-(xdata-mean1)**2/(2*std1**2)) + A2*np.exp(-(xdata-mean2)**2/(2*std2**2)) + A3*np.exp(-(xdata-mean3)**2/(2*std3**2))

def Gauss_4(xdata, H1, A1, mean1, std1, A2, mean2, std2, A3, mean3, std3,  A4, mean4, std4):
    return H1 + A1*np.exp(-(xdata-mean1)**2/(2*std1**2)) + A2*np.exp(-(xdata-mean2)**2/(2*std2**2)) + A3*np.exp(-(xdata-mean3)**2/(2*std3**2)) + A4*np.exp(-(xdata-mean4)**2/(2*std4**2))

def Gauss_5(xdata, H1, A1, mean1, std1,  A2, mean2, std2,  A3, mean3, std3,  A4, mean4, std4, A5, mean5, std5 ):
    return H1 + A1*np.exp(-(xdata-mean1)**2/(2*std1**2))  + A2*np.exp(-(xdata-mean2)**2/(2*std2**2)) + A3*np.exp(-(xdata-mean3)**2/(2*std3**2)) + A4*np.exp(-(xdata-mean4)**2/(2*std4**2)) + A5*np.exp(-(xdata-mean5)**2/(2*std5**2))


def get_popt(f):
    means = find_peaks(f, prominence=0.05, width=1)[0]
    if len(means) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(means) == 1:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_1, np.arange(len(f)), f, p0=[0, f[means[0]], means[0], 3, 
                                                                    f[means[1]], means[1], 3], 
                              bounds=([0, 0.9*f[means[0]], 0.9*means[0], 0],
                                      [1, 1.1*f[means[0]], 1.1*means[0], 10]))
    elif len(means) == 2:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_2, np.arange(len(f)), f, p0=[0, f[means[0]], means[0], 3, 
                                                                 f[means[1]], means[1], 3], 
                              bounds=([0, 0.9*f[means[0]], 0.9*means[0], 0, 0.9*f[means[1]], 0.9*means[1], 0],
                                      [1, 1.1*f[means[0]], 1.1*means[0], 10, 1.1*f[means[1]], 1.1*means[1], 10]))
    elif len(means) == 3:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_3, np.arange(len(f)), f, p0=[0, f[means[0]], means[0], 3, 
                                                                    f[means[1]], means[1], 3,
                                                                    f[means[2]], means[2], 3])
                
    elif len(means) == 4:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_4, np.arange(len(f)), f, p0=[0, f[means[0]], means[0], 3, 
                                                                   f[means[1]], means[1], 3,
                                                                   f[means[2]], means[2], 3,
                                                                   f[means[3]], means[3], 3],
                                bounds=([0, 0.9*f[means[0]], 0.9*means[0], 0, 0.9*f[means[1]], 0.9*means[1], 0, 0.9*f[means[2]], 0.9*means[2], 0],
                                      [1, 1.1*f[means[0]], 1.1*means[0], 10, 1.1*f[means[1]], 1.1*means[1], 10, 1.1*f[means[2]], 1.1*means[2], 10]))
    else:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_5, np.arange(len(f)), f, p0=[0, f[means[0]], means[0], 3, 
                                                                   f[means[1]], means[1], 3,
                                                                   f[means[2]], means[2], 3, 
                                                                    f[means[3]], means[3], 3, 
                                                                   f[means[3]], means[3], 3])
    return popt
```

Is there a way to assemble the number of gaussian functions and the parameters such that it is defined only by the number of peaks without all this if / else comparisons and individual functions definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an implementation of a [Gaussian Mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) which [has already been done](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html). So, ideally, use `scikit-learn` instead of your implementation.

However, to answer your question, you just need a vectorized version of your `Gauss_X` which can be easily achieved by using numpy vectorization. As far as I understand it's a likelihood function for a given gaussian mixture.

```py
import numpy as np
def Gauss_N(xdata, means, stds, mixture_weights):
    nominator = (np.tile(xdata, (len(means), 1)) - means.reshape(-1, 1))**2
    denom = np.tile((2*stds**2), (len(xdata), 1)).T
    densities = np.exp(nominator/denom)  # note, you need to also add a normalizing constant!
    likelihoods = np.sum(densities, axis=1)
    likelihood = np.sum(likelihoods*mixture_weights)
    return likelihood

xdata = np.array([4, 5, 6])
means = np.array([1, 2])
stds = np.array([1, 2])
mixture_weights = np.array([0.3, 0.5])
Gauss_N(xdata, means, stds, mixture_weights)  # simply works
```

Now you should be able to do `popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss_N, ...)` in each of those `if-else` clauses.

---

This probably won't work out of the box, your example is quite convoluted in many aspects, but should give you an idea of how it could be done.